# Where can I find latest version of iManage API documentation?

Tags: api, imanage

I am looking for a complete online reference for iManage's latest API. On googling, can see references to iManage v2 documentation, but that seems to be bit old and where can I find latest API if at all there is one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version which is constantly updated is available at https://help.imanage.com/hc/en-us/sections/360000214214-iManage-Work-REST-API-Documentation - you'll need a login to IManage's support site to access this though. If you don't have credentials you can raise a ticket with your support provider to get access.

If you have an on premises server that's licenced for the API, you'll find the documentation for that specific version at https://YOURSERVERNAME/api-docs/

Comment: thanks Davison, besides that is there any compatibility info for respective iManage Work versions wrt API or any docs that assist with upgrading iManage?

Answer (score 0):

iManage has 3 different versions of API's

- COM API > This is a legacy classic api which is reaching EOL on Dec 2023. So it is not recommended any more.
- REST API v1.0 > EOL already reached (Dec 2022)
  If you're on-prem technically you can use REST API 1.0 till iManage Work 10.4.4 (but please validate) but you will not have any support from iManage in case of any issues
- REST API 2.0 (also called iManage Universal API)
  This is the latest version and going forward you need to use this version. And if I am not wrong this is supported from iManage Work 10.2.3.
  You can find latest documentation at [iManage Universal API 2.0](https://help.imanage.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412558535067-iManage-Work-Universal-API-Reference-Guide-REST-v2-#overview)

Or you can find your Work server specific documentation https://YOURSERVERNAME/api-docs/ (Provided you entered API license while installing iManage Work software)